# Violation of UNIQUE KEY Constraint in SqlBulkCopy Execution

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

I am trying to develop a solution to automate the migration of data from several client databases to a central database of the same structure using SqlBulkCopy in C#. It threw an exception of "Violation of Unique Key Constraint" because some tables have got unique key columns with some unique values in them (that I completely understand).

So my major challenge now is to somehow get the program to skip the record coming from the source database (client DB) that has a duplicate unique key on destination database (central DB), get the corresponding Primary Key Value on the destination 
database (central DB) and overwrite the primary key value of the skipped record on all tables (in the client DB) in which it exists as a foreign key.

This is my biggest challenge I have ever faced in my software development experience yet. And to whoever that can help me out of this, I will be forever in your debt.

Thanks.

Comment: Id use a temporary table and then use the MERGE function to achive that

Comment: But how do I get to detect the tables with unique constraint issue for which I would use a temporary table?

Comment: Have you considered using SqlServer's built in replication features?

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy is good for copying data in bulk from A to B but it can't do potentially complex re-keying. If you want to use the SqlBulkCopy class then I would split the job into 2 parts; first prepare the client DB by making sure there will be no dupe keys (duplicates of keys in the central database), secondly transfer the data using SqlBulkCopy.

In order to find out which tables have unique indexes or constraints on them you can use this query;

```
select distinct quotename(object_schema_name(i.object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(t.name) as table_name
from sys.indexes i
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = i.object_id
where i.is_unique = 1 
order by 1
```

There are various ways to approach making sure the client DB has no dupe keys. Some ideas are;

- Add a client identifier to all the keys. For example, prefix all the keys in the first client database with 'A', all the keys in the second client database with 'B' etc. The downside to this approach is that it often requires some effort to move from numeric to alphanumeric keys.
- Use defined numeric ranges for all the keys in each client database. For example, all the keys in the first client database start at zero, all the keys in the second client database start at 1,000,000, all the keys in the third client database start at 2,000,000 etc. The downside to this approach is the risk of overlapping ranges if one client database requires more than the allocated range worth of keys in one sequence.
- use uniqueidentifiers for keys in all the client databases. The downside to this approach is the potential performance issue with uniqueidentifiers and the human-unfriendly appearance of them.

Unfortunately I can't think of an easy way to do what you want.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to respond. But the client DB has no duplicate keys at all because they all have unique keys created in some of the tables. Actually, the clients have been operating as stand alone, so some base records were created for all the clients to work. So getting them to the central server will fail because of the unique constraints. so what I need to do is get the corresponding PKey of the record on the server and update it on the client where they appear as a foreign key.